# How mock private method with nullable args

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk

I'm use MockK for unit test. How i can mockk private call with nullable and not nullable args?

My  method:

```
private fun trySaveLogin(session: Session, login: String, passwordHash: String?, passwordHashNoSalt: String?, userInfo: UserInfo) { // doWork}
```

Already tried:

```
every { loginPresenter["trySaveLogin"](allAny<Any>())  } just Runs
every { loginPresenter["trySaveLogin"](any<String>(), any<String>(), any<String>(), any<String>(), any<UserInfo>()) } just Runs
```

Everything return error :

```
io.mockk.MockKException: can't find function trySaveLogin(-4d6de1423b10ebb8, ...) for dynamic call
```

Comment: Don't know how to do that with MockK but if you end up mocking private methods, chances are that you have badly designed classes in your hands.

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace and any other information from the exception?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
every { loginPresenter["trySaveLogin"](any<Session>(), any<String>(), any<String>(), any<String>(), any<UserInfo>())  as Unit } just Runs
```